# navigate to new page in iPhone

Tags: iphone, animation, navigation, uibutton, buttonclick

I am new to iPhone developer,

On click of button, i want to navigate to a new page with this animation, `UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft`

How should i do this ?

```
  -(void)btnClick{

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; 
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7]; 
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES]; 
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:NO]; 

        [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

When i click on btn Animation happens but i am unable to navigate to new page.

**Any Help Will be Appriciated !**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"View" bundle:nil];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Flip" context:nil]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7]; 
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut]; 
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
[viewController release];
```

viewController is the page u want to navigate to.

Pop:

```
    [UIView  beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.375];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: dude it's working, but when i click on Back button in my 2nd page, Animation should flip from Right, but it happens like `popViewController`.

Comment: where should i write your **EDIT** ?

Comment: but my back button is not Custom, it is part of navigation controller so, where should i add ? give me this answer and i will accept your ans.

Comment: lol....if u want to add extra piece of code u need to customize it.do customize as it doesnt do any harm for your navigation controller.write the code in that link in view2 and before popping add animation.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't specifying which views you want to swap in and out. At the moment you are just setting where the animation happens and what type of animation it is.

You need something like this.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7]; 
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES]; 
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:NO]; 
[view1 removeFromSuperview];
[self.view addSubview view2];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I recommend reading this documentation as I dont think you understand the `ViewController` and `View` relationship entirely. There are different ways of transitioning between `ViewControllers` and individual `views`.

Just in the case of using this method your `view1` would be `LicAppViewController.view` and assuming you `PlanPage` is a view then `view2` is just `PlanPage`.

Comment: what to write in place of view1 and view2 ? i want to navigate from `LicAppViewController` page to `PlanPage`

Comment: `[LicAppViewController removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview PlanPage];`  when i write this i gets warning in my first line as `+removefromsuperview` method not found and on second line i gets error `Expected :`.

Comment: you cant remove a ViewController it must be its view that you're removing so LicAppViewController.view